# A limit lemma involving inverses in need of proof or revision

Tags: real-analysis, limits, inverse

Let $f(0),g(0)\to0$, then $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{g^{-1}(x)}{f^{-1}(x)}$

I'm looking for a proof to this

I'm not sure if this is correct or has limitations on what $f$ and $g$ can be but I'm trying to prove something larger relating arbitrary functions to hyperellipses and this has me stuck. I haven't taken analysis yet so this may be really simple but I'm not sure what to.

Comment: Are $f$ and $g$ differentiable?

Comment: @Mr.X, not at 0 but around 0, yes, this is for functions that act like $\sqrt x$ and the like

Comment: "Let $f(0),g(0)\to 0$" ?  Please add some details to the hypotheses. Where are these functions defined, how smooth are they, are they injective etc.

Comment: $f,g$ are regular, smooth functions defined around $x=0$ and that was meant to mean $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=0$ and $\lim_{x\to0}g(x)=0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Assuming $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$ exist)Here $f, g$ are differentiable around $0$. We can apply L'hospital rule and we get,

$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \lim_{x\to0}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} $. By Inverse Function theorem we have $f'(x) = \frac{1}{(f^{-1})'(f(x))}$ and $g'(x) = \frac{1}{(g^{-1})'(g(x))}$. Now since $f(x),g(x) \rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow 0$. Therefore we get,
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \lim_{x\to0}\frac{(g^{-1})'(x)}{(f^{-1})'(x)}$$

Again since $f^{-1}(0) = g^{-1}(0) = 0$, we have $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{g^{-1}(x)}{f^{-1}(x)} = \lim_{x\to0}\frac{(g^{-1})'(x)}{(f^{-1})'(x)}$. Thus we get
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{g^{-1}(x)}{f^{-1}(x)}$$

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize you could do L'hopital's in reverse with those criteria, interesting.

Comment: The limit $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$ need not exist. Consider $g(x) = \sqrt[3]{x^2}$ and $f(x) = g(x) + x^2\sin \frac{1}{x^3}$. Then $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \to 1$, but $\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$ is unbounded. L'Hospital's rule says **if** the limit of $\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$ exists (and some other assumptions), then the limit of $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ exists too and is the same. It doesn't work in the other direction. (cc @JacobClaassen)

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thanks. @DanielFischer